Optimization problem with two (inequality) constraints
I am trying to solve the following optimization problem:
$\begin{align}\min_{\mathbf{c}_{k}} \sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{q_k}{c_k} \\
\text{s.t. } c_k &\geq t_k \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{K} c_k &\leq F \tag2\label2
\end{align}$
$c_k, F, q_{k}, t_k >0$.
The problem is simple but tricky. If \eqref{1} does not exist, the optimal value of $c_k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,K$ will be $
c_{k}^{*}=\frac{F\sqrt{q_k}}{\sum_{n=1}^{K}\sqrt{q_n}}.$
What would be the solution if the two constraints were considered?
For the case without the first constraint, we will have
$\begin{align}\min_{\mathbf{c}_{k}} \sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{q_k}{c_k} \\
\text{s.t. }
\sum_{k=1}^{K} c_k &= F \tag3\label3
\end{align}$
I changed inequality \eqref{2} to equality \eqref{3} because optimality holds true to equality. Thus, the Lagrange function of the problem can be expressed as
$$
 \mathcal{L}\left(\left\{f_{k}\right\},\nu\right) =
\sum_{k=1}^{K}
{\frac{ q_{k}}{c_{k}}}
+
\nu \left(\sum_{k=1}^{K}c_{k}-F\right)
$$
where $\nu$ is the Lagrange multiplier for constraint \eqref{3}. The partial derivatives are
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial c_{k}} &= -\frac{ q_k}{c_{k}^{2}}+\nu = 0 \\
    \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \nu} &= \sum_{k=1}^{K}c_{k}-F = 0
\end{align}
that yields
\begin{align}
    \nu &= \frac{ q_k}{c_{k}^{2}} \tag4\label4\\
\sum_{k=1}^{K}c_{k} &= F \tag5\label5
\end{align}
Solving \eqref{4} yields
$$c_{k} = \sqrt{\frac{ q_k}{\nu}} \tag6\label6$$
Substituting \eqref{6} into \eqref{5} yields
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt \nu} = \frac{F}{\sum_{k=1}^K \sqrt{q_k}}$$
Hence
$$c_k^*=\frac{F \sqrt{ q_k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{K} \sqrt{{ q_k}}}$$

Note that \eqref{2} will be satisfied as an equality at optimality.

Did you have any ideas for how the solution would change based on the constraints?

I recommend updating your question to show how you obtained $c_k^*$ for the problem without \eqref{1}.  It is correct but will help the case for reopening the question.

I already updated my question, @RobPratt.

Now what happens when you apply the same approach with \eqref{1}?

@RobPratt I could not handle the inequality constraint with (1).  I do not know how to solve it properly; for example, my problem now has two constraints: equality and inequality, which is confusing to me.

Introduce another Lagrangian multiplier $\mu_k$ for each inequality.

@RobPratt, I have seen that in the answer below, but I do not know how to solve that system of equations.

First write out the equations like you did for the simpler problem, and maybe somebody can help you solve them.

@OsamaThabet Perhaps there is not closed form solution. However, it is a convex optimization problem. You can solve it effectively by some solver.


Want to solve: $\min f(\mathbf{c})$ subject to $g_k(c_k)=t_k-c_k\leq0$ and $h(\mathbf{c})=\sum_{k=1}^Kc_k-F\leq0$.


Solve $$\begin{cases}
\nabla f(\mathbf{c})+\nabla h(\mathbf{c})\lambda+\sum_{k=1}^K\mu_k\nabla g_k(c_k)&=0\\
h(\mathbf{c})\lambda&=0\\
g_k(c_k)\mu_k&=0
\end{cases}$$ for all $\lambda,\mu_k\geq0$.
Then, you can use Second order sufficient conditions to verify.
Note: Please tell me if there are any errors.

Thanks, but how to solve these 3 equations now?

You use any method you prefer for solving nonlinear equations. The key is that these equations are unconstrained in the state variables so it is easier to work with than the original system

@whpowell96, but how would I deal with the multiplier of the first constraint?

$\lambda,\mu_k\in\mathbb{R}$, so just treat it together with $c_k$ as unkown. The number of equations is enough for solving.

@math... you cannot ignore the inequality constraints on the multipliers. They are essential. There is no standard method for symbolically solving nonlinear equations. Writing out these KKT conditions for your system may be easier to work with. There is a lot of literature on numerical techniques for these problems.
